# How can I display the date in Swift 4 without including the year?

Tags: swift, date

How can I just remove the year when using the DateFormatter Full Style. I would like it to display the date like this, ex:( Thursday, October 4). Excluding the year.

Currently I have:

```
func todaysDate() {
    dateLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: NSDate() as Date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.full, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.none)
}
```

Comment: [`setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla)? (aside from providing your own custom date format)

Comment: You can't use dateStyle at all if you want something other than one of the stock formats. You have to use a custom dateFormat. See rmaddy's answer, although creating a date formatter for each conversion is inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a properly localized but custom format, you need to use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`.

```
func todaysDate() {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEEMMMMd")
    dateLabel.text = df.string(from: Date())
}
```

`EEEE` gives the full weekday name. `MMMM` gives the full month name. `d` gives the day of the month.

Based on the user's locale, the resulting format will be in the correct order with appropriate punctuation added.

Also note there is no reason to use `NSDate`.

As a side note, I would refactor your code to be more like this:

```
func todaysDate() -> String {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEEMMMMd")
    return df.string(from: Date())
}
```

And then where you are currently calling:

```
todaysDate()
```

I would do:

```
dateLabel.text = todaysDate()
```

Comment: Maybe add `df` as an extension on `DateFormatter` to avoid creating a new date formatter each time this function is called

Comment: I'd also write a function `weekdayMonthDateFor(date:)` that takes a `Date` as input, and then write a function `todaysDate()` that calls `weekdayMonthDateFor(date:)` using today's date as a parameter.